# How to detect authenticated user with FormsAuthentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How do I tell if a user is authenticated (logged in) using FormsAuthentication?

```
<authenticaion mode="Forms">
   <forms protection="All" cookieless="UseCookies"/>
</authentication>
```

Comment: what code do you have thus far.?

Comment: You want to see, if the user used forms authentication or you want to know whether the user is authenticated?

Comment: in your config file please paste the code starting from this line <authentication mode="Forms">
so we can see what you have setup as well

Comment: Checkout the following links
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.authenticate.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.validateuser.aspx
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication#Authentication_vs._authorization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check whether the user is logged in you can use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`.

Authentication type can be found out by `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.AuthenticationType` to know the authentication type used

Comment: You mean ...Request.LoginUserIdentity...?  AuthenticationType is NTLM but how is that possible since this is a web app?  Of course, I'm running it local out of VS.NET.

Comment: It can also be this.User.Identity at a page. Authentication can either by FormsAuthentication / WindowsAuthentication / Cusom and Windows authentication uses NTLM

Comment: If it's a web app with authentication mode="Forms", why is NTLM coming into play?  Any web user should not be using NTML right?

Comment: Yes, you need to see how its configured in IIS

Comment: Did you login using forms auth?

Comment: This is actually for YAF, which uses membershipprovider but still has a forms authentication entry in its web.config.  Maybe time for a new post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code - based on `FormsIdentity` class

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.security.formsidentity.aspx

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User != null)
  {
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
     if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is FormsIdentity)
     {
         .....
     }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure that's what you meant, but on server side code:

Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible way is using ***FormsAuthenticationModule*** module in web.config and create forms authentication cookies.

you can refer to [Explained: Forms Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx)